# I need to remove a word from a spreadsheet in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

I have a very simple excel spreadsheet; need to remove the word "Phone:".  Find and replace doesn't work for DELETING a word:(  I'm a newbie, please keep it simple for me...
regards.

Answer (score 0):

Find and replace should work if the word "Phone" is simply text and not created as part of a formula. Before starting the "Find and Replace" utility (keyboard shortcut: ctrl+h) in Excel, make sure that only one cell within Excel is selected. It doesn't matter which cell just so long as multiple cells are not highlighted. If multiple cells are highlighted when trying to use "Find and Replace," then it will only search for the keyword ("Phone") in the highlighted cells. Also, make sure there aren't any unusual options selected in the "Find and Replace" utility.

If this doesn't work, could you please post a screenshot so further troubleshooting can be done. Also note that if "Phone" is surrounded by spaces, the spaces aren't removed and it can lead to double spaces, beginning spaces, and trailing spaces. If this is the case, please as a new question (preferably with a picture of part of the affected worksheet) to solve this problem

[image: Excel Find and Replace Image]

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the word by leaving the Replace field blank in the Find and Replace window.